# Why are plant buds called 'eyes'?

Tags: terminology, history, etymology

I was reading [the etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=inoculate&allowed_in_frame=0) of the Latinate English verb 'inoculate' which contains the following part that generated the question entitled above:

> [...] *inoculare* "graft in, implant a bud or **eye** of one plant into another," from in- "in" (see in- (2)) + oculus "bud," originally "**eye**" (see [eye](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=eye&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.)).

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/67296?rskey=YO8Le7&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid326256277) confirms 'eye' as a synonym of 'bud,' but I doubt that 'potato buds' generated this meaning because it already existed in Classical Latin that (I am assuming) South Americans did not speak in the 1500s when [they introduced potatoes to the Spaniards](http://wonderopolis.org/wonder/do-potatoes-see-with-their-eyes).

Comment: Maybe its cause the buds can "open" into a larger structure, like an eye lid can "open" in general. That's just a random guess though

Comment: Also, my answer is just one perspective. There can be many more reasons :D

Comment: You might get a better answer on [linguistic.SE](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: if he's looking from a linguistic perspective, then you might get a better answer like Remi said in linguistic stack exchange

Comment: I think this question was wrongfully closed. True, this term likely has some esoteric beginnings, but if the etymology of the word-form can be traced, than perhaps so could the origin of that usage.

Comment: @theforestecologist - can you?

Comment: @AliceD who knows? But I think because none of us immediately know doesn't mean that the answer is *not* known or that any potential answer is necessarily opinion based.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about etymology not biology.

Comment: Early usage of "eye" in a bud context can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QDQwAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA4-PA117&lpg=RA4-PA117&dq=Practical+Husbandman+%26+Planter+eye&source=bl&ots=vUu3tZYr8S&sig=ACfU3U1aQT0mWo8dlUZ1-8ORVNXXHdfQhg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsyIGcqK3tAhW7GVkFHRzfARwQ6AEwD3oECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Practical%20Husbandman%20%26%20Planter%20eye&f=false) in Volume 1 (1733) of *Practical Husbandman and Planter ,or, Observations on the Ancient and Modern Husbandry, Planting, Gardening, &c*. Page 117 of Number II regarding licorice and p80 in Number III regarding potatoes.

Comment: [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/eye) suggests usage for potatoes originated 60 years earlier. "Of potatoes from 1670s"

Comment: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eye) suggests that a secondary definition for "eye" is `something having an appearance suggestive of an eye: such as`... `an undeveloped bud (as on a potato)` providing some support for the appearance theory

Comment: [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/inoculate) provides the following for the word inoculate: `inoculate (v.)
mid-15c., "implant a bud into a plant," from Latin inoculatus, past participle of inoculare "graft in, implant a bud or eye of one plant into another," from in- "in" (from PIE root *en "in") + oculus "bud," originally "eye" (from PIE root *okw- "to see").`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a look at a potato and observe each of its eyes. You will see that each of them has two parts:

1) An "eyebrow" : this is a vestigial leaf

2) A small bud in the axil of that leaf

Thus, the two of them together form an eye + eyebrow

The eyes are not evenly distributed in a potato plant. One side may have just one or two but the other side will have lots of them. This is because that is the growing spot!

Examples:

[image: Eyes of a potato]

Comment: Please provide some support/reference for this answer if possible. Right now it comes across as your own opinion.